# django getting values from form

Tags: django, get, filtering, django-queryset

I need to filter the table by column and value, nothing better comes to my mind (I'm new in django)

*view*

```
   def get_queryset(self):
        column = self.request.GET.get('column')
        condition = self.request.GET.get('condition')
        queryset = Table.objects.all()

        if condition == 'contains' and column == 'title':
            queryset = Table.objects.filter(
                title__icontains=self.request.GET.get('title')
            )

        elif condition == 'greater' and column == 'quantity':
            queryset = Table.objects.filter(quantity__gt=self.request.GET.get('title'))
        elif condition == 'greater' and column == 'distance':
            queryset = Table.objects.filter(distance__gt=self.request.GET.get('title'))
        elif condition == 'lower' and column == 'quantity':
            queryset = Table.objects.filter(quantity__lt=self.request.GET.get('title'))
        elif condition == 'lower' and column == 'distance':
            queryset = Table.objects.filter(distance__lt=self.request.GET.get('title'))
        elif condition == 'equals' and column == 'quantity':
            queryset = Table.objects.filter(quantity__exact=self.request.GET.get('title'))
        elif condition == 'equals' and column == 'distance':
            queryset = Table.objects.filter(distance__exact=self.request.GET.get('title'))

        return queryset
```

i knew it looks like ****
please give me more elegant idea)

there my table[image]

the idea is as follows, the user selects a column and the condition by which the table will be filtered
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    column = request.GET.get('column')
    condition = request.GET.get('condition')
    condition_dict = {'contains':'icontains','greater':'gt','lower':'lt','equals':'exact'}
    title = request.GET.get('title')
    kwargs = {
        '{0}__{1}'.format(column, condition_dict[condition]): title,
    }
    queryset = Table.objects.filter(**kwargs)
    return queryset
```